# Как написать сгруппированное where в laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, where

Есть контроллер в котором выполняется запрос с многочисленными условиями. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
$houses = House::with('areas')->
          where('format_house', '=', $format_house);

$houses = $houses->where('price', '<', $value);
$houses = $houses->where('area', '>', $value);

$houses = $houses->where('address', 'LIKE', "%" . $value . "%")
                    ->orWhere('metro', 'LIKE', "%" . $value . "%")
                    ->orWhere('description_metro', "LIKE", "%" . $value . "%");

$houses = $houses->orderBy('price')->
            orderByDesc('created_at')->
            orderByDesc('area');

   $houses = $houses->paginate(16);
```

В конец подключаются еще условия. Обращу внимание, что через конструкцию orWhere подключаются альтернативные условия. Проблема в том, что если выполняется альтернативное условие поиска, то отключаются подключенные ранее условия по полям format_house, price, area. Мне нужно же что-то вроде этого, покажу как в SQL это выглядело бы:

```
Where ((`format_house` = 'Аренда') and (`price` < 1000) and (`area` > 5) 
and ((`address` LIKE '%Пушкина%') or (`metro` LIKE '%Пушкина%') or (`description_metro` LIKE '%Пушкина%')));
```

Можно как-то в ларавел обернуть дополнительными "скобками" условие where, чтобы условие or распространялось только на тройку значений, и не отменяла другие предыдущие where?

Всем спасибо, если ответите!

Comment: вы пробовали открыть доку по ларавел то?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#or-where-clauses

Comment: так точнее будет https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#logical-grouping

Comment: @teran, да пробегался по документации ларавел. Хорошо, допустим у меня такой запрос: <code>$users = DB::table('users')
           ->where('name', '=', 'John')
           ->where(function (Builder $query) {
               $query->where('votes', '>', 100)
                     ->orWhere('title', '=', 'Admin');
           })
           ->get(); </code>  Могу ли я в анонимную функцию второго where добавить еще параметры, чтобы например определить условия для votes или title значение?

Comment: параметры не можете. а вот замыкание на внешнюю область видимости сделать можете, используя `use ($title, $votes)`

Comment: @teran, спасибо помог!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

привет я делал это так

P.s
`use ($yourVariable)` можешь передать переменные

```
$houses = $houses->where(function ($query) use ($yourVariable) {
   $query->where('address', 'LIKE', "%" . $yourVariable . "%")
   ->orWhere('metro', 'LIKE', "%" . $yourVariable . "%")
   ->orWhere('description_metro', "LIKE", "%" . $yourVariable . "%");
});
```

Comment: Уже так и сделал, но все равно спасибо!